# Deploying an angular 2+ app into cloud Foundry using Ng serve

Tags: ibm-cloud, angular5, cloud-foundry, angular2-cli

I am attempting to deploy an angular app into IBM Cloud - Cloud Foundry using the CF CLI.

It always seems to fail and doing some research it requires a node script for the start command in package.json. Therefore it is failing due to me having a Ng serve command.

Any ideas about getting around this issue?

Comment: Can you include the actual error message you're seeing?  It's crucial to share details like that so everyone can understand what is happening with your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after having a play I realised that the research that I have done is misleading and I have finally figured it out now. Thought that I would post my findings here to save someone else the trouble:

- Firstly, unlike doing a ng serve locally, you will need to build the project first i.e npm run-script build. This should give you the dist directory.
- Secondly I had a slightly invalid manifest.yml. This is a sample of the file that I have used which finally got it to work:

  ```
  ---
  applications:
  - name: <App Name>
    path: dist <- This points to the compiled code
    random-route: true
  ```

Hope that this helps someone in the future.

Comment: lol maybe a dumb question, but does cf automatically call the `start` script after deployment?